# Stellar age determination - code

Tags: star, exoplanet, stellar-astrophysics, age

I'm trying to determine the age of some stars. I have many parameters that characterize these stars: $T_{eff}$ ,log ${g}$ ,$[Fe/H]$, $V$... I've tried to use the isochrones package but so far no success. I was wondering if any of you might have any recommendations!

Comment: What does "...but so far no success..." mean? If you can add some further information about what you tried and what results you obtained and what exactly was it about the results that you feel indicate they are unsuccessful, that would be helpful. Also do you mean this? https://isochrones.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you! Can't remember well but couldn't seem to get it to run right. Ended up using PARAM, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's always okay to post an answer to your own question and accept it. It's helpful to future readers seeing how a problem was solved, helps the site a tiny bit by increasing the answered question fraction, and usually you can pick up a few more reputation points which eventually leads to having more site functionality available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PARAM - http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/param

Cheers,